# Vue.js component inside an SVG element is not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component called legend that should embed SVG elements inside a template that places the actual SVG tags:

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="pie-chart" :width="outerwidth" :height="outerheight">

    <legend ref="legend" :series="series" :position="positionLegend" :options="{}" ></legend>   

    </svg>
```

But the legend component does not get rendered the output is:

```html
   <div id="graphbox">
       <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1691" height="14" class="pie-chart">

       <legend series="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" position="[object Object]" options="[object Object]"></legend>

        </svg>
    </div>
```

Does vue not parse within SVG tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components inside `<svg>` should work fine but you'll need to rename `legend` to something else. `legend` is a standard HTML element name so Vue will get confused.

Also make sure that you've registered the component correctly, either locally or globally. Usually Vue will warn you if you've forgotten to register a component but in this case it won't because `legend` is a standard HTML element.

Here's a complete example, similar to the one in the question:

```js
const myLegend = {
  template: `<circle r="10" cx="20" cy="20" :fill="color" />`,
  props: ['color']
}

new Vue({
  el: '#graphbox',
  
  components: {
    myLegend
  },
  
  data () {
    return {
      outerheight: 50,
      outerwidth: 50,
      color: '#ff0000'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="graphbox">
  <svg :width="outerwidth" :height="outerheight">
    <my-legend :color="color"></my-legend>   
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, I had already tried renaming it as I thought that may be the problem, but forgot to match the new name when importing the component in CamelCase as required by Vue.  Thankyou for your proof to show me it is possible.